# Proving martingale property of $N_t = Z(M_{t\wedge s} - M_{t \wedge r})$ for martingale $M$

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, local-martingales

(Stochastic calculus and Brownian motion, LeGall, page 80).

> Suppose $M = (M_t)$ is a martingale. Also, let $Z$ be a bounded random variable which is $\mathcal{F}_r$ adapted. Then we like to show that for any $0 \leq r < s$, 
>   $$N_t = Z(M_{t\wedge s} - M_{t \wedge r})$$ 
>   is a martingale.

**My attempt:** 
 $Z(M_{t\wedge s} - M_{t \wedge r}) \in L_1$, should be fine since both $Z$ and $M$ are bounded. I am not sure how to show it is adapted.
Finally we need to show the martingale identity. Suppose $v \geq r$, then we have 
$$\mathbb{E} \{Z(M_{t\wedge s} - M_{t \wedge r}) \mid \mathcal{F}_v \} = Z \mathbb{E} \{(M_{t\wedge s} - M_{t \wedge r}) \mid \mathcal{F}_v \} = Z (M_{v\wedge s} - M_{v \wedge r})$$
where in the first equality we use the fact that $Z \in \mathcal{F}_r$, and $v \geq r$. This proves the result for this case. However, I don't know how to get the result for general $v$.

Thanks for you helps in advance.

Comment: "and hence the bound is in $L_1$" could you elaborate why you believe that this is true? Note that $X<\infty$ does not imply $X \in L_1$.

Comment: My mistake. thanks for reminding me. I edited the response. In fact, I couldn't show even the $L_1$ yet.

Comment: That's not surprising because it is in general wrong. If your assertion was correct, it would imply that $(M_r)_{r \leq t}$ is a martingale for any local martingale $M$... which is clearly wrong.

Comment: Do you impose $r \leq t$ ? Or could $Z$ be rather $F_t$-adapted ? I cannot imagine how $N_t$ is adapted (with respect to $F_t$, right?) as you state it.

Comment: It seems too much for the general local martingale. I have modified the statement of the problem according to LeGall (page 80). The integrability should be fine in this case, but still addaptedness and martingale identity is not. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, we note that

$$N_t = \begin{cases} 0, & t \leq r, \\ Z (M_t-M_r) & t \in (r,s), \\ Z (M_s-M_r), & t \geq s. \end{cases} \tag{1}$$

Since $Z$ is, by assumption, $\mathcal{F}_r$-measurable and $(M_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}$-adapted, this implies, in particular, that $(N_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}$-adapted. Moreover, $M_t \in L^1$ together with the boundedness of $Z$ entails $N_t \in L^1$ for all $t \geq 0$. It remains to check that

$$\mathbb{E}(N_t \mid \mathcal{F}_u) = N_u \quad \text{for all $u \leq t$}. \tag{2}$$

We consider two cases separately.  If $t \geq u  \geq r$ then it follows from the $\mathcal{F}_r$-measurability of $Z$ that

$$\mathbb{E}(N_t \mid \mathcal{F}_u) = Z \mathbb{E}(M_{t \wedge s}-M_{t \wedge r} \mid \mathcal{F}_u).$$

Because of the martingal property of $(M_t)_{t \geq 0}$ we have

$$ \mathbb{E}(M_{t \wedge s}-M_{t \wedge r} \mid \mathcal{F}_u) = M_{t \wedge s \wedge u} - M_{t \wedge r \wedge u} \stackrel{t \geq u}{=} M_{u \wedge s} - M_{u \wedge r},$$

and so

$$\mathbb{E}(N_t \mid \mathcal{F}_u) = N_u, \qquad r \leq u \leq t. $$

In particular,

$$\mathbb{E}(N_t \mid \mathcal{F}_r) = N_r \stackrel{(1)}{=} 0. \tag{3}$$

It remains to consider the case $u < r$. If $t \leq r$ then, by $(1)$, $N_t = 0$ and so

$$\mathbb{E}(N_t \mid \mathcal{F}_u)=0=N_u.$$

Suppose now that $t \geq r$. Since the tower property gives

$$\mathbb{E}(N_t \mid \mathcal{F}_u) = \mathbb{E} \bigg[ \mathbb{E}(N_t \mid \mathcal{F}_r) \mid \mathcal{F}_u \bigg], $$

we conclude from $(3)$ that

$$\mathbb{E}(N_t \mid \mathcal{F}_u) = 0 = N_u.$$

This finishes the proof of $(2)$.

Comment: Nice proof. Thanks, very helpful.